# How do I NOT trigger the onChange callback in Angular 11 a Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

In my project I save information by every change in an input field with the registerOnChange method. But in a particular usecase I don't want to call the callback from the registerOnChange. I

Here is a summary of my code

```
  textInputControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
...
   this.textInputControl.registerOnChange(() => {
      this.textInputChangeHandler();
    });
...
this.textInputControl.setValue("trigger the registerOnChange"); 
this.textInputControl.setValue("NOT trigger the registerOnChange").doNotTriggerOnChange(); // Hope the solution will something like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `{ emitEvent: false }` as the second argument.

```
this.textInputControl.setValue("NOT trigger the registerOnChange", { emitEvent: false });
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but u help me in a right direction. I will look further. Thank u!